# c# How get value from memory address and cast it in primary type?

Tags: c#

I have reference to value in memory, but I can't get this value and cast him on my type. Please, say me what I should write so that i will get value or say why i can't do this

My example:

```
ListItem<string> item = new ListItem<string>("hell to world"); //ListItem<T> is class
unsafe
{
   TypedReference itemRef = __makeref(item);
   IntPtr reference = **(IntPtr**)&item;
   long address = (long)reference;
}
```

I can use `__refvalue`. this method require `TypedReference` and type to which you want cast value. This work, but I don't known how get this `TypedReference` from `void*`, `IntPtr` or `long`. I hope somebody help me

UPD: I wrote a simple bidirectional list in hope that it will work at least a little faster than default List. Well, and as usual in the bidirectional lists there are pointers to the next and previous element. But i used objects of the same class instead of a pointer to this object, so i tried to work with pointers and memory.

UPD: i wrote this just out of my personal interest, not more

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: In addition to being more explicit about what you're actually trying to do here (probably the goal is unwise or unnecessary), please also explain in what way the code you posted is insufficient. What does that code do that is different from what you actually want?

Comment: I wrote a simple bidirectional list in hope that it will work at least a little faster than default List. Well, and as usual in the bidirectional lists there are pointers to the next and previous element. But i used objects of the same class instead of a pointer to this object, so i tried to work with pointers and memory.
UPD: i write this just out of my personal interest, not more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_PtrToStructure_System_IntPtr_System_Type_

If it is not what you want you can see another `Marshal` and `MarshalEx` methods. This classes are created for work with pointers in C#.

Comment: In case with my class throwed ArgumentException: "The specified Type must not be a generic type definition.". But this not work also with structure, for example "Point". Throwed ExecutionEngineException with empty message. Also i see "Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)". Maybe in the pointers in my case it makes no sense?